# Is there a way to Collect[] for more than one symbol?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Oftentimes you find yourself looking for polynomials in multiple variables. Consider the following expression:

```
a(x - y)^3 +  b(x - y) + c(x - y) + d
```

as you can see this is clearly a polynomial in `x-y`. Is there an equivalent of [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html), that works on more complicated expressions than just a single variable? I would like to have something similar to

```
Collect[%, x - y]
(* --> a(x - y)^3 + (b+c)(x - y) + d *)
```

however. `Collect` can not work on `x-y`. Of course you could solve this first example by substituting `x-y -> z`, then `Collect` the `z`, and afterwards substitute back like so:

```
a(x - y)^3 +  b(x - y) + c(x - y) + d /. x-y->z
```

gives

```
d + b z + c z + a z^3
```

Then

```
Collect[a z^3 + b z + c z + d, z]
```

gives

```
d + (b + c) z + a z^3
```

Now undo the substitution by running `% /. z -> x - y`. This gives the desired result:

```
d + (b + c) (x - y) + a (x - y)^3
```

So this is good. For obvious polynomials, we can solve this. But what about real world examples? Would you have guessed that

```
d + b x + c x + a x^3 - b y - c y - 3 a x^2 y + 3 a x y^2 - a y^3
```

is exactly the same polynomial? How would you Collect `x-y` here, as you cannot do the substitution?

Comment: I'd make the substitution `expr /. x -> y + z` before applying `Collect[]` (and possibly `Simplify[]` before that) myself...

Comment: which version are you using? This works in v.8.0.4

Comment: I am using mathematica 7

Comment: I think it has "worked" since version 3. [Quotes in use because non-variable "variables" implementation is a bit of hackery. Nested quotes in use because "'non-variable' variables" is an oxymoron. Nested quotes in use...]

Comment: @J.M. your idea is good though i dislike the notion of substituting, since I don't see how it can be done programmatically. If I used that technique, this would react badly, if z was defined beforehand.

Comment: @niklasfi: That's easily solved with a module: `Module[{z},Collect[expr/.x->y+z,z]/.z->x-y]`. The only limitation is that `expr` must not contain `z`. Or use `Collect[expr/.x->y+#,#]/.#->x-y]&@Unique[]` to lift even that limitation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I am more inclined to try something that leverages Mathematica "knowledge" of polynomials.

In fact, in Mathematica 7 and 8, you can collect by $x-y$. However, it only works if $(x-y)$ is explicitly apparent in the form of the argument seen by the `Collect` function.

So, this works:

```
Collect[a (x - y)^3 + b (x - y)^2 + c (x - y) + d, x - y]
```

But, this doesn't:

```
Collect[Expand[a (x - y)^3 + b (x - y)^2 + c (x - y) + d], x - y]
```

I would use `PolynomialReduce` but I don't have an automated way for doing what you need.

Nevertheless it looks promising as the following does return `{a, b, c, d}`:

```
Flatten[
    PolynomialReduce[
        d + c x + b x^2 + a x^3 - c y - 2 b x y - 3 a x^2 y
             + b y^2 + 3 a x y^2 - a y^3,
        Table[(x - y)^i, {i, 3, 1, -1}],
        {x, y}
    ]
]
```

But I can use this approach for other factorizations.

For example, consider the following expansion `Expand[z (x - y)^6 + w (x - y)^4 + t (x - y)^2 + s]`. Using this expansion I am able to retrieve the coefficients in terms
of powers of `x^2 - 2 x y + y^2`:

```
Flatten[
    PolynomialReduce[
    s + t x^2 + w x^4 - 2 t x y - 4 w x^3 y + t y^2 + 6 w x^2 y^2 - 
        4 w x y^3 + w y^4 + x^6 z - 6 x^5 y z + 15 x^4 y^2 z - 
        20 x^3 y^3 z + 15 x^2 y^4 z - 6 x y^5 z + y^6 z, 
    Table[(x^2 - 2 x y + y^2)^i, {i, 3, 1, -1}],
    {x, y}
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, technically you can do it programmatically:

```
CollectMany[expr_, a_ - b_] := Block[{cZf23},
  Collect[expr /. a -> b + cZf23, cZf23] /. cZf23 -> (a - b)]
```

Using your example:

```
In[134]:= CollectMany[
 d + b x + c x + a x^3 - b y - c y - 3 a x^2 y + 3 a x y^2 - a y^3, 
 x - y]

Out[134]= d + (b + c) (x - y) + a (x - y)^3
```

Notice I use the symbol `cZf23`. You want this to be some random and HIGHLY unlikely to be in use.

In the general case you may need a slightly more complicated definition:

```
CollectMany[expr_, a_ - b_] := Block[{cZf23},
  Collect[expr /. a -> b + cZf23, cZf23] /. cZf23 -> (a - b)]
CollectMany[expr_, a_ + b_] := Block[{cZf23},
  Collect[expr /. a -> cZf23 - b, cZf23] /. cZf23 -> (a + b)]
```

I'm not 100% sure if `CollectMany[polynomial, a + b]` will trigger in the same way as `CollectMany[polynomial, a - b]`, so you may need to do things this way.

---

An updated version I would use instead is:

```
CollectMany[expr_, a_ + b_] := Block[{z = Unique[]},
  Collect[expr /. a -> z - b, z] /. z -> (a + b)]
```

Using `a_ + b_` will match `x - y` properly.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke: The main reason why I'm hesitant to use `Module` is because I've run into the unfortunate bug where defined variables inside of `Module` are cleared but the symbols don't disappear from the Mathematica kernel. In tight loops, this manifests as a memory leak. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867892/reducing-memory-usage-in-an-extended-mathematica-session) on SO addresses this.

Comment: Does this happen even if you `Quit[]` the kernel?

Comment: @R.M: If you quit, then the symbols get unloaded. But for a continuous session, Module will slowly leak memory. This has been a known bug since version 7. I'm not sure if it still exists at this moment.

Comment: @Mike You can avoid usage of `Block` and `Unique` as well as `Module` simply by using a [formal symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264).

Comment: @Mike In your updated version usage of the symbol `z` is dangerous since this symbol can be used inside of `expr`.

Comment: Providing that `expr` does not contain formal symbols, one can rewrite `CollectMany` as: `CollectMany[expr_,a_+b_]:=Collect[expr/.a->\[FormalZ]-b,\[FormalZ]]/.\[FormalZ]->(a+b)`.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do this is:

```
Normal[Series[d + c x + b x^2 + a x^3 - c y - 2 b x y - 3 a x^2 y
    + b y^2 + 3 a x y^2 - a y^3, {x, y, 3}]]

(* 
 ===> d + c (x - y) + b (x - y)^2 + a (x - y)^3
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

This deals with what more or less is a general case: f is a polynomial in g, where g is another polynomial and we want to "collect" with respect to g. Actually, I once posted similar code on the MathGroup but could not find it so I decided to write it again. (I did not have the time to write nicer code so this is pretty rough...).

The code will only work when f actually is a polynomial in g (with constant coefficients) otherwise it will simply return f itself. I have had to use HoldForm to prevent Mathematica rearranging linear terms in some cases.

Here is the code:

```
CollectPolynomial[f_, g_, vars_] := 
 Module[{s = PolynomialReduce[f, g, vars], u, v, coeffs, z, p}, 
  u = s[[1, 1]]; v = s[[2]]; coeffs = {v}; 
  While[FreeQ[v, Alternatives @@ vars] && u =!= 0, 
   s = PolynomialReduce[u, g, vars]; u = s[[1, 1]]; v = s[[2]]; 
   coeffs = Prepend[coeffs, v]]; 
  p = Table[z^i, {i, 0, Length[coeffs] - 1}].Reverse[coeffs] /. 
    z -> HoldForm[g]; If[Simplify[ReleaseHold[p] - f] === 0, p, f]]
```

For example:

```
g = x^2 + y^2 - 1;f = Expand[Sum[g^i, {i, 0, 5}]] + 3;

CollectPolynomial[f, g, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> 4 + Hold[-1 + x^2 + y^2] + Hold[-1 + x^2 + y^2]^2 + 
>  Hold[-1 + x^2 + y^2]^3 + Hold[-1 + x^2 + y^2]^4 + 
>  Hold[-1 + x^2 + y^2]^5
> ```