# Proper use of arbitrary number of variables

Tags: numerical-integration, variable-definitions, core-language

So, I'm working on a project where the number of independent variables is not fixed.

Consider a problem of $N$ independent variables, $\boldsymbol{r}$.

I want to perform different things with them. Amongst them, I want to consider (multidimensional) integration, etc.

### Variables definition

My first question regarding this topic, is the definition of the variables to perform algebraic manipulation. My first though was to use

```
variables[N_]:=Table[x[i],{i,1,N}]
```

However, in some situations, (e.g. with Block), I cannot use these variables as I use x1,x2,.... e.g.

```
Block[{x[1]=2},x[1]^2]
```

gives an error.

(my current naive solution is to use):

```
variables[N_] := Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, N}];
```

Is there any more standard solution?

#### Sums, integrals

This question also holds for the problem of computing integrals for arbitrary dimensions.

How can I tell *Mathematica* to compute

```
Integrate[f[{r1,r2,...,rn}], {r1, 0, 1}, {r2, 0, g[r1]},...,{rN, 0, h[{r1,r2,...,"rN-1"}]}]
```

Most of the times I will be interested in numerically compute the integral, but nevertheless, how do I tell *Mathematica*? I tried the simple "naive"

```
Integrate[1, Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, variables[3]}]]
```

but it gives an error.

Comment: Try `Integrate[1, Sequence @@ Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, variables[3]}]]`.

Comment: You can use something like `Table[Unique["x"], {5}]` to create variables.

Comment: You might find some useful ideas in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/how-to-create-functions-of-arbitrary-number-of-variables) previous question and its answers. Also, in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/423/whats-the-purpose-of-the-unique-function) one.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @b.gatessucks: The Sequence works for Integrals, but not for sums.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: dump: because it has an holdall attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use:

```
variables[n_, sym_String: "x"] := Unique @ Table[sym, {n}]

variables[5]

variables[5]

variables[3, "Q"]
```

> ```
> {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
>
> {x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}
>
> {Q1, Q2, Q3}
> ```

Note the difference on the second call.

For work in `Sum` et al. you can leverage the fact that a plain `Function` evaluates its arguments:

```
vars = variables[7, "z"];

Sum[Multinomial @@ vars, ##] & @@ ({#, 0, 1} & /@ vars)
```

> ```
> 13700
> ```